# Ubuntu 13.04 installer hangs on "Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source"

Tags: 13.04, system-installation

I've let the installer run for about 4 hours, but the installation of Ubuntu 13.04 32 bits it's still stuck in this message:

> Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source

Now, I'm stuck with my phone until this is solved.

Computer specs: Acer Aspire 3610 - 2GB DDR2 - Intel Celeron M processor 1.5ghz - Intel 915GM x86/MMX/SSE2

Comment: See

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/512998/installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-stuck-on-configuring-bcmwl-kernel-source-i386

Answer (score 5):

Don't use No Substitute's example! Modprobe wl may not have a pid of 29798 on your system. It did on mine.

Run this to find the pid of modprobe wl:

```
ps -eaf | grep modprobe
```

That should give you an output of something similar to this:

```
root     29798 29126  0 08:59 ?        00:00:00 modprobe
```

Take the first number after root, in my case 29798, but it will be different for you, and then run:

```
sudo kill -9 29798
```

That will kill the modprobe wl process and move on to the next step in installation.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing without enabling 3rd party drivers. That worked for me and my Broadcom wifi still was able to connect.

Comment: Already tried this, and still does the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried installing using Ethernet port?

Comment: No. I think I'll just try a different distro.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
sudo kill -9 X
```

(X = pid of `modprobe wl`)

That will halt that process and just skip to the next in the installations process.
Worked for me.