# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS stuck on 'Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source (i386)'

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, hp, 32-bit

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my HP Pavilion dv5000, but it's stuck during the installation on 'Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source (i386)'. Where is the problem? How to fix it? I tried several times to install it but it doesn't help. Please help me.

Comment: are you trying to install a 32 bit version? or are you using a 64bit install image?

Comment: I'm trying to install a 32 bit version.

Comment: does the computer have a 32 or 64 bit cpu?

Comment: the computer have 32 bit cpu.

Comment: have you tried running from a terminal in the live session "sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source"?

Comment: no i haven't. So first i should trie running from the terminal in the live session and then normally install ubuntu?

Comment: bcmwl-kernel-source: command not found

Comment: sorry, my fault. your advice help. now it works. thanks for help

Comment: here I'll put it in the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` from a terminal in the live session before you start installation to create a cached binary file that it will load instead of originally compiling the source again.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-Installation:
Make sure 'Install 3rd party software' is unchecked.

This will allow the install to complete, but the wireless card will have no firmware and will therefore not function.

Post-Installation:
Using another mode of internet connection, locate your specific model here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

And follow the instructions to install the driver manually.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu and thanks for chipping in! We could really use your help here: http://askubuntu.com/unanswered